# Getting .asmx file in browser is fine, getting .asmx?WSDL returns an empty page

Tags: iis-7, sharepoint-2010, wsdl, asmx

I created a webservice in a .dll and put this in the windows\assembly directory.
I followed all steps shown in the following URL and stopped at the paragraph "Creating a Windows Application to Consume the Web Service", because my consumer is a Lotus Domino agent:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms464040.aspx

There are two installations, where it worked just fine, now I did this on a third computer and when I browse the URL to the asmx file in a browser (IE9, Firefox 12 & Chrome 19) I get the normal answer from the IIS 7. But when I click on the link for the service description
(.../DominoImporter.asmx?WSDL) all I get is an empty page! IE9 shows the default 404 page and in Chrome I have a white page with no source. Firefox shows an error message, that describes the empty page with a header of type XML.

This doesn't work:
hostname/_vti_bin/DominoImporter.asmx?WSDL

This works:
hostname/_vti_bin/DominoImporterwsdl.aspx

I searched half this day for differences between the three installations / computers but found nothing!
All forum help found by Google also discussed other problems than mine.

I think there has to be someone, who already has experienced the same problem & can give me advice!?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now I found a solution, I deinstalled Visual Studio 2010 and after this I deinstalled Sharepoint Foundation 2010. Then I reinstalled Sharepoint Foundation 2010 and installed Visual Studio 2012.

Then when I load the WSDL again, the resulting web page in the browser isn't empty anymore!

Wrote this, maybe someone else might need this solution in the future.

Turned out, that my Sharepoint installation was corrupt. Couldn't clarify this before out of time pressure with a higher prioritized project.

Answer (score 0):

1. comment following line in web.config of webservices project.

   ```
   <add name="ContentTypeHttpModule" type="Porthos.Signup.Extras.ContentTypeHttpModule, ContentTypeHttpModule"/>
   ```
2. Right click your service and view in browser.
3. Click on Service description and it will show you wsdl.

Additionally it will also resolve updating web reference error.